# How to redirect output with color in gedit

Tags: command-line, bash, gedit, colors

I have a simple script to print color text in terminal which I've directed to log file too.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\033[01;32mGreen color" > ~/Desktop/color.log
```

When I run from terminal cat color.log, it prints with green color but when I open file with gedit it shows as

```
[01;32mGreen color
```

Is it possible to redirect with color in gedit?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably not. There might be an option or a plugin in gedit that allows it to interpret this sort of [ANSI color escape code](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php), but that's unlikely since the point of those codes is to display color in terminal-based tools, not a GUI tool like gedit.

I suggest you simply use a terminal based tool to read your files instead. For example, you can use `less -R` which can interpret color codes correctly:

```
less -R  ~/Desktop/color.log
```

Comment: Your answer is somewhat useful but not this answer as it does not fulfill my requirement and you also said **the point of those codes is to display color in terminal-based tools, not a GUI tool like gedit.** Yes. I agree, question is similar but not an answer.

Comment: @daisy I don't understand, the other question seems to be asking for exactly the same thing you are: for a way to show ansi escapes as colors in gedit. What is the difference? The basic answer is no, that isn't possible.

Comment: okay. The basic answer is no, that is not possible -I should have known better.

Comment: Well… not until someone write a GEdit extension that achieves this but I’m unaware of any existing solutions.